# Show that the signed distance from a $C^2$ boundary is $C^2$ on the boundary

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

Let $\partial D$ be a $C^2$ regular boundary of an open, bounded, and connected subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define $$s(x)=\begin{cases}d(x,\partial D)&\text{if }x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{D}\\-d(x,\partial D)&\text{if }x\in \overline{D}\end{cases}.$$

I want to show that $s%$ is twice differentiable.

I know I will need to use that $\partial D$ is $C^2$ because if there was a corner in $\partial D$ then $s$ would not even be differentiable.

The definition of $C^2$ regular I am using is that for some finite covering $U_i$ of $D$, there is a collection of functions $\phi_i$ such that each function and its inverse are $C^2$, the image of $U_i$ under $\phi_i$ is the unit ball, and $\phi_i(y)$ is above the $x_n$ axis if $y\in D$, below the $x_n$ axis if $y\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{D}$ and on the $x_n$ axis if $y\in \partial D$.

This is my attempt:

Let $x\in \partial D$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$.

Let $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Either $x+h\in \overline{D}$ or $x+h\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{D}$.

Suppose that $x+h\in \overline{D}$.

Then $$s(x+h)=d(x+h,\partial D)=\inf_{y\in \partial D}||x+h-y||.$$

So $$\frac{s(x+h)-s(x)}{||h||}=\frac{\inf\limits_{y\in \partial D}||x+h-y||-0}{||h||}$$

Similarly, if $x+h\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{D}$, then $$\frac{s(x+h)-s(x)}{||h||}=\frac{-\inf\limits_{y\in \partial D}||x+h-y||-0}{||h||}.$$

I need to show that both of these difference quotients approach the same value as $h\to 0$.

I know that $y=\phi_i^{-1}(z)$ for some $z\in B(0,1)\cap \{x_n=0\}$ and some index $i$ and that $x+h=\phi_i^{-1}(\phi_i(x+h))$.

So, for $x+h\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \overline{D}$ I know that
$$\frac{s(x+h)-s(x)}{||h||}=\frac{\inf\limits_{y\in B(0,1)\cap\{x_n=0\}}||\phi_i^{-1}(\phi_i(x+h))-\phi_i^{-1}(z)||-0}{||h||}.$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Maybe there is some way to take out the $\phi_i^{-1}$, but I'm not sure if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Possibly $s$ is $C^2$ on $\partial D$, but there can be points away from $\partial D$ where $s$ is not differentiable at all. For example, the graph of $s$ along the red line will look like $|t|$, having a sharp corner at the midpoint.

[image: region with two bulbs, with a red line between the bulbs]